# Django class based view, wrong language value when using 'queryset' attribute

Tags: python, django

When I use `translation.get_language()` in the `queryset` attribute of a class based view it returns an incorrect value when changing the language.

```
class LandingPageOverview(ListView):
    model = LandingPage
    context_object_name = 'landingpages'
    template_name = 'landingpage/overview.html'
    queryset = LandingPage.objects.filter(language=translation.get_language())
```

When I use `get_queryset` the right value is returned.

```
class LandingPageOverview(ListView):
    model = LandingPage
    context_object_name = 'landingpages'
    template_name = 'landingpage/overview.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    return LandingPage.objects.filter(language=translation.get_language())
```

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, the language is evaluated when class is loaded at first time. Try for example this:

```
def a(x=[]):
    x.append(1)
    print x


a()
a()
a()
a()
```

result will be:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

**EDIT**:

you could do something like this:

```
class LandingPageOverview(ListView):
    model = LandingPage
    context_object_name = 'landingpages'
    template_name = 'landingpage/overview.html'

    @property
    def queryset(self):
        return LandingPage.objects.filter(language=translation.get_language())
```

and use it like you want:

```
l = LandingPageOverview()
l.queryset
```